# Python data handling - Split 3D array efficiently into two using binary mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to split a large 3D array into two 3D arrays along a certain axis (in this case axis 0) using a binary list as means of identifying where to place each 4x4 frame.

In reality the dataset is much larger (10000x100x100) and therefore my current implementation using for loops and if commands, then concatenating, is far too slow.

Any ideas how to speed this up would be greatly appreciated. Very simple example of input below.

```
AnArray = np.zeros((20,4,4))
    
BinaryList = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
    
#In this instance I would expect two output arrays with dimensions 11x4x4 and 9x4x4
    
OutputHigh = [[[]]]
OutputLow = [[[]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
>>> anArray = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=(20, 4, 4))
>>> BinaryList = np.array([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]).astype(bool)
>>> anArray[BinaryList].shape
(11, 4, 4)
>>> anArray[~BinaryList].shape
(9, 4, 4)
```

Comment: THANK YOU. This works fantastically. Such a simple seeming answer but this has just reduced my computing time from approx 20 mins per iteration to about 30 seconds.